# Can I XCOPY Deploy a Windows Service?

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-services, installutil

I have a windows service that is already installed on a server, and I have a new version of the executable and linked assemblies. The normal procedure I use for installation of a new version is:

1. Stop the service
2. Uninstall the service using `InstallUtil /u`
3. Overwrite the service executable and linked assemblies with the new ones
4. Install the service using `InstallUtil`
5. Start the service

I'm wondering if I'm doing too much? Is there any problem with just doing the following:

1. Stop the service
2. Overwrite the service executable and linked assemblies with the new ones
3. Start the service

I don't think that uninstalling/installing is necessary but couldn't find any formal confirmation.

Comment: The most *obvious* issue is that involves taking the system down; for that reason, I tend to use `AppDomain`s - the service can then be self-updating (executing the *actual* system somewhere writeable), with the exe just handling the process spin-up and app-domain management; zero downtime to update

Comment: @MarcGravell That's an excellent idea and sounds pretty reusable. I haven't done much programming with AppDomains so is there a skeleton or template or blog post you could point me to that would get me started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the service has already been installed, yes, you can xcopy deploy your new executable and assemblies without any problems.

All `installutil` is doing is creating the appropriate registry entries that point to the service executable. If you've previously ran `installutil` to create those entries, then there is no need to repeat this step when you change out the executable.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading. Or rather, you are answering the question in the title ("Can I XCOPY" -> yes), but the last question he asks is "Is there any problem with just doing the following" to which the answer is **no** :-)